# React/Antd: Dynamic form fields based on JSON response

Tags: reactjs, forms, parent-child, dynamically-generated, antd

I'm trying to create a form that dynamically maps fields based on a JSON response.

I currently have a dummy object that I'm setting in state, but the final stage will receive the data from an external API call. The dataset may change over time with key/values being added or deleted based on business needs. In lieu of this I need to create a smart component that takes an initial set of data and maps a "Read-only" field for every key/value pair in the object.

The second concern is the actual form layout. I have an initial scaffolding below, and I've only hard-coded the columns and rows. How can I implement logic that will create two column rows from the data response?

Any thoughts/help on this is hugely appreciated!

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Form, Button, Input, Row, Col } from 'antd';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import './style.css';

class OpportunityDetails extends Component {
constructor() {
      super();
    this.state = {
      disabled: true,
      formLayout: 'horizontal',
      opportunityDetails: [
          {
              CustomerName: "",
              Field2: "Some data",
              Field3: "Some data",
              Field4: "Some data",
              Field5: "Some data",
              Field6: "Some data",
              Field7: "Some data",
              Field8: "Some data",
              Field9: "Some data",
              Field10: "Some data",
              Field11: "Some data",
              Field12: "Some data",
              Field13: "Some data",
              Field14: "Some data",
              Field15: "Some data"
          }
      ]
    };
    this.toggleSwitch = this.toggleSwitch.bind(this)
}

  toggleSwitch() {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      disabled: !previousState.disabled,
      enabled: previousState.disabled
    }))
  }

  modifyRoute(){
    alert("Sending you to the modify floor");
  }

  uploadRoute(){
    alert("Sending you to the upload sector!")
  }

  render() {
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    const { enabled } = this.state;


    return (
      <div className={}>

 /// Button Group
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
        <Col span={4}>
          <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.modifyRoute}>Modify Docs</Button>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4}>
          <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.uploadRoute}>Upload Docs</Button>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4}>
          <Button disabled={enabled} onClick={this.toggleSwitch}>
            Unlock Quote
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>

/// Form section with columns and rows for all key/value pairs
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder="{value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      </Row>
            <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key}>
          <Input placeholder={value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
      </Row>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<OpportunityDetails />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Was there any problem with iteration functions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to setup an iterative function to create the Antd elements

Comment: iteration over objects and arrays is not something Antd or React related, it is basic JavaScript functions. I recommend you spend more time in learning JavaScript, Then React and you will be able to apply everything to every UI library, Antd, Bootstrap Material ...

Comment: I know how to iterate over an object but the way that Antd displays the title and text is what's throwing me off. I can setup mapping from with the return section like `opportunityDetails.map(key => (<Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
      <Col span={10}>
        <Form.Item label={key=opportunityDetails.key}>
          <Input placeholder={opportunityDetail.value} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>` but that's not playing well with Antd because of how you define the _Title_ and the text inside the actual `<Form.item>` component

Comment: well that is the problem, map is over the array, but inside your array you have an object, and you can not map over object and you should use, for instance for each key, value pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take Amir's comment seriously. And once you do, you'd probably restructure your data so it would be more handy (and readable):

*I don't know why `opportunityDetails` has to be an array, I adjusted to that anyway. Though it will add complexity as you would see*

1.) This is how you want your data to look like (you will understand later why):

```
/*[
   { itemKey: "CustomerName", itemValue: "" },
   { itemKey: "Field2", itemValue: "Some data" }
   .... and so on
]*/


opportunityDetails: [
  {
    CustomerName: "",
    Field2: "Some data",
    Field3: "Some data",
    Field4: "Some data",
    Field5: "Some data",
    Field6: "Some data",
    Field7: "Some data",
    Field8: "Some data",
    Field9: "Some data",
    Field10: "Some data",
    Field11: "Some data",
    Field12: "Some data",
    Field13: "Some data",
    Field14: "Some data",
    Field15: "Some data"
  }
].map(obj => {
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  return objKeys.map(itemKey => {
    return {
      itemKey,
      itemValue: obj[itemKey]
    };
  });
})
```

the following steps and patterns below are JSX (or react) specific; what I'm trying to say is this is the most common way of rendering an `array of JSX elements` in react:

2.) Create a method which will return an *array of JSX*, I used .map because .forEach will not work (you may want to search why on your own).

```
renderDynamicElWrapper() {
  return this.state.opportunityDetails.map(items => {
    return (
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
        {this.renderDynamicEl(items)}
      </Row>
    );
  });
 }
```

*assuming opportunityDetails will have more than 1 item, we need to have another method and iteration similar to the one above*

```
  renderDynamicEl(els) {
    return els.map(el => {
      return (
        <Col span={10}>
          <Form.Item label={el.itemKey}>
            <Input placeholder={el.itemValue} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      );
    });
  }
```

3.) Finally, below would be how the return of your `render` method will look like:

```
return (
      <div>
        <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
          <Col span={4}>
            <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.modifyRoute}>
              Modify Docs
            </Button>
          </Col>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={this.uploadRoute}>
              Upload Docs
            </Button>
          </Col>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Button disabled={enabled} onClick={this.toggleSwitch}>
              Unlock Quote
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        {this.renderDynamicElWrapper()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

P.S: I would advice to master `.map` and how to return an array of jsx from a method because %100 of the time you will encounter the same pattern in React projects.

Comment: The data responses we've been getting back have been inside arrays. We're working with the API team to have them return responses as objects. Can I use the above logic to map over an Object with nested objects?

Comment: Rather an array of separate objects like you listed as an example for how to structure my data like `{ itemKey: "CustomerName", itemValue: "" },
   { itemKey: "Field2", itemValue: "Some data" }`

Comment: @JCalkins89 yes. Did you try it? it was actually working in my side. `opportunityDetails` will become array of arrays instead of array of objects

Comment: It works when opportunityDetails is an array of a single object with key/value pairs but when I change the data to an array of objects the Title fields all become _itemKey_ and _itemValue_ and the values that should be the Titles all shift to the fields. I have a Stack Blitz here showing what I mean(https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5t7vmv). Is there a better way to map if the response is an object of nested objects?

Comment: My bad with #1 I probably did not express what I mean good enough. It's true I already did the conversion/mapping part for you. If you would just revert the original `opportunityDetails` you will get the correct result from your Stack Blitz. If you notice opportunityDetails....map function inside the constructor, that `.map` did the job of restructuring `opportunityDetails`

Comment: Oh yeah no worries! I changed it back and everything works fine. Is there a way for me to throw `console.logs` throughout the component to see what's actually taking place at each step? Like right after the .map conversion in state and the subsequent functions for `renderDynamicElWrapper()` and `renderDymanicEl(els)`?

Comment: yeah sure. What you would want is to return later when calling the method, so you should assign the return of .map first to a `hold` variable, and finally return `hold` at the last line:

`renderDynamicElWrapper() {
  const hold =  this.state.opportunit.... map... function contents
  return hold;` By the way, if this answer helped you I would appreciate if you can tag it as it is

Answer (score 0):

```
<Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
  <Col span={10}>
     {opportunityDetails.map(detail=>{
          return detail.forEach(([key,value])=>(
               <Form.Item label={key}>
                   <Input placeholder={value} />
               </Form.Item>
             )
          )
      })}
  </Col>
</Row>
```